# Inserting new values on vector (in C language)

Tags: c, function, pointers, function-pointers

I'm trying to create a function which elaborates an array. I'm not sure how to input a vector or an array on a function and then returning the modified vector/array (I'm trying to use pointers).

Is this possible or I'm using pointers in the wrong way?

```
int newValue(int *p){
    // modify the vector
    return p;
}

int main(){
    int a[6]={4,6,7,3,1,8};
    int *p;
    p = a;
    p = newValue (p);
```

(This is the assignement:
Given an array of VET_SIZE elements of integers：
Write a function to insert a new value in a particular index of
the array, and move the following elements forward without
deleting existing values except for the value of last element)

Comment: Write a constructor function: creates a 'vector' struct and returns a pointer to it, (you will need malloc). Then, add the vector as another argument to your 'newValue()' function.  You could add in your initial 6 values by calling 'newValue' 6 times in a loop or writing another 'addArray' function that takes an array and length.

Comment: You use the word "vector" while the assignment and C language use "array". Is that for a particular reason? If not, I'd recommend you edit the question to better reflect what you mean.

Comment: Then, it is unclear with which of the aspects you have trouble with. Do you know how to read the values of elements of an array? To write them? Do you know what a pointer is? Do you understand that a pointer to the first element of an array can mostly serve as a stand-in for the array (and do you understand just *why* that is so)? Lastly: Do you understand the assignment (i.e, can you produce one or two examples of an array before the operation and the desired state after the operation)?

Comment: I had trouble with using pointers and arrays in a function, but dont worry I have been alreasy answered.
An example:
Original array:
4 6 7 3 1 8
//insert a[3]=10
The array after insertation:
4 6 7 10 3 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm not sure how to input a vector or an array on a function and then reurning the modified vector (I'm trying to use pointers)

All you need to do is to pass the array itself, you can then modify it directly in function `newValue`. Something like this:

```
void newValue(int *p, size_t n){
    // modify the 2nd item
    p[1] = 10;
}
```

Then in `main` just call it:

```
newValue(a);
```

A couple of notes:

- Your `newValue` does not need to return anything (`void` is ok), as you can change the array directly.
- `void newValue(int *p, size_t n)` is the same as `void newValue(int p[], size_t n)` - because array `decays` to pointer.
- Usually it's good to pass an additional parameter `n` about the input array size, so inside your function you can check to make sure you don't have out-of-bound access.

Comment: Will not work for adding extra values:(

Comment: Thanks! I'm new to the concept of pointer and using it in a function makes it harder, but i'm slowly understanding it.

Comment: I think the assignment asks for shifting the higher-indexed elements right.

Comment: Yes, I dont need to add extra values

Comment: @FuriaseFTW not really a classic vector, then.